# Reading ExtJS writer root property using Jersey rest web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, extjs, jersey

I have successfully implemented Jersey for simple WebService calls (queryparams and simple objects) but when I try to `sync` a store or `save` a record, jersey doesn't understand the `rootProperty` of the writer. It doesn't know where to start and it cannot `Consume` the json record ExtJS is sending. Unfortunately `rootProperty` is mandatory according to ExtJS when you transform the data to JSON so I can't do without it. I can obviously use `Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` and transform the object myself but I'm trying to take advantage of Jersey's automatic object marshalling etc.

What is the general practice used to `.sync` store data or `.save` records?

EDIT: I don't think the problem is with my object's JSON. My store's proxy is configured as follows:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'ext/AnnouncementHelper/myFunction',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'processMessage'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true
        }
```

What this does is create a POST request with the following parameter:

```
data={id: 1, description: 'status 1'}
```

My model is configured as follows:

```
public class AnnouncementStatus {

    private int id;
    private String description;

    @JsonCreator
    public AnnouncementStatus() {

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

My function declaration is:

```
@POST
@Path("myFunction")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myFunction(AnnouncementStatus status)
```

This gives me the following error in java:

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

I'm guessing jackson doesn't like that my object is starting with the `data=` but I cannot avoid this since it is mandatory to have a root property when using stores and records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem I had although not to the question at hand.

I still have no idea how to read the writer's root property using jersey but I found out I don't need to anymore since if we change our proxy's writer to have `encoding: false` it is not mandatory to set a `rootProperty` and it just sends the records as an array. This is understood by Jersey's serializer and it can decode the data into objects correctly.